# How to send an email on event (with event details) in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, email

How do I send an email with event details when some event occurs in Windows 7, for example when any user logs on?

I've tried to use Event Viewer, but I haven't found out how to attach event details to the email's body.

Comment: It's not very straight-forward, and would depend on the specific 'details' you wish to gather, and for which event(s). Perhaps edit your question and provide those specifics?  There's good info/tutorial on it [here on Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/otto/archive/2007/11/09/find-the-event-that-triggered-your-task.aspx).

Comment: @techie007 thanks for reply. I've updated question

Comment: So all you want is an email when someone logs on? Do you need to know who logged on or anything like that?

Comment: Is there a specific event log entry you are attemping to base this off of?  I'd use a different approach, create a Task that is triggered by login that runs a script to get current user and then email it.  Such a script is pretty straight forward in PS.

Comment: @techie007 yes, email with event message which can be seen in Event Viewer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the task scheduler from the (Control Panel -> Administrator's Tools).
It has the option to run a script, program or action, depending on some trigger (like someone logging on, running a program etc)
Here's an example setup dialog (you are interested in the event "at log on") :
[image]

Comment: And how do i get event message to emails body?

Comment: (First, in addition to manually creating the task above, you can more easily setup the task thru the event log. Find Event 4624 and pick "Attach taqsk to this Event..".)

Comment: Then the task needs to be exported (to an XML file), edited to include event fields and then imported back into the task scheduler as a new event. Here's an example of someone doing something similar - http://blogs.technet.com/b/otto/archive/2007/11/09/find-the-event-that-triggered-your-task.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This seems simpler if you want the event text too

http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2010/06/16/getting-event-log-contents-by-email-on-an-event-log-trigger.aspx

Comment: Can you please share actual solution instead of just posting a link?

Comment: On an event is the option "Attach Task To This Event", here you can select an email action. If you want an attachment you can generate a file with a previous action and use that as attachment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the job, edit XML file of the task and add value to ValueQueries. Import the job again and edit mail details. You can include Event Details and any information in the event.

Below article explains step by step on how to do the same:
http://vijredblog.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/task-scheduler-event-log-trigger-include-event-data-in-mail/

Comment: Need more than a link. Expand to show the solution other wise this is a trite answer and the link may eventualy break.

Answer (score 0):

1. Export the job from the task scheduler
2. Edit the XML file of the task, add a `ValueQueries` node inside . Add `value` nodes inside it. For example:
   `<EventTrigger>
   ...
   <ValueQueries>
   <Value name="EventData">Event/EventData/Data</Value>
   </ValueQueries>
   ...
   </EventTrigger>`
3. Import the job again and edit mail details. You can use `$(EventData)` to include the event details

Please note that not all Windows Server versions admit this XML schema, but I guess that any recent version (WS2012 onwards) will be fine. For example: WS2008 (non R2),  which uses http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task schema, does not like it.