# Monitor a Folder and Email New Files

Tags: windows, software-rec, script

I am looking for a Windows application or script that will monitor a folder (that I define), and when a new file is added, it will email said file to a particular email address (that I define). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Security Auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771395(v=ws.10).aspx)<sup>[[XP]](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399)[[7]](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/advanced-security-auditing-in-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx)</sup> will allow you to monitor file and folder access.

As for email the file, I’m not sure if that is built-in (it’s mostly for logging). If not, then what you can do is to [configure](https://superuser.com/questions/389105/how-to-send-an-email-on-event-with-event-details-in-windows-7) the Task Scheduler to send an email when an event (from the audit) appears. (Though I don’t know if there is a way—at least not an one—to extract the filename form the event and provide it to the task to be used as an attachment for the email.)

Comment: I am sure it is possible to parse the file in powershell, and if you post an example one, I can write that up

Comment: Parse what? An event log file? `o.O` You would need to [access the event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6b9a7h8(v=vs.71).aspx), not the file.