# How can I monitor a specific directory in Windows 11 to see when a new file is added?

Tags: windows, powershell, python, batch-file

I have a shared folder within my company that often gets new builds added to it. It is my job to do QA on the builds in that folder but I am getting tired of just having to check the folder every day to see if there is a new build or not. I'd like to setup a Python script, batch file, powershell program, Visual Basic, etc. to essentially send me an email or alert me in some way to their being a new file in there.

I'm on windows 11.

I have found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/389202/monitor-a-folder-and-email-new-files) which essentially asks the same thing but there is not a good answer and any other questions I've found of this seem to be related to Windows Vista or some other very old version of Windows.

EDIT:

@Gantendo suggested to use FolderChangesView and I like that and will be using that. I now have a text file that gets updated whenever files are changed, but I do not have the email portion working

Comment: Workstation auditing is the only practical way I know how to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191823/notification-if-something-was-change-created-in-your-folder

Comment: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FolderChangesView link](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html#google_vignette)

What I ended up doing was using FolderChangesView and setting up a powershell command to run from within that main menu to alert the user with a popup. Not the same as sending an email, but it works either way.

Powershell command used: `PowerShell -Command "Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework;[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Files have been edited in directory')"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a  FileSystemWatcher for just this task, it is what it is built for.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/a-reusable-file-system-event-watcher-for-powershell/

An a full sample implementation of the watcher.
https://powershell.one/tricks/filesystem/filesystemwatcher

Above is a powershell implementation that will raise an event to let you know if a file was added, deleted, modified, etc. Form there you can use whatever messaging method you like when an event is detected, you can use Send-MailMessage, it still works but it slated for obsolescence, so no idea how long it will stick around.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.3

So you could make the break and go straight to System.Net.Mail as well which should be long term supportable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail?view=net-7.0

Example:

```
Function Send-Email {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [String]$From,
        [String[]]$To,
        [String]$Subject,
        [String]$SMTPServer,
        [String]$Body,
        [String[]]$Attachments
    )
    $email = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $From, $To, $Subject, $Body
    $email.To.Add($To)
    $email.isBodyhtml = $true
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer)
    $smtp.Port = 25
    $emailAttachment = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($Attachments)
    $email.Attachments.Add($emailAttachment)
    $smtp.Send($email)
}
```

http://vcloud-lab.com/entries/powershell/send-email-using-powershell-with-net-object-system-net-mail-mailmessage

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using CMail: https://www.inveigle.net/cmail

I have used this before to send me notifications - I am not familiar with FolderChangesView, however if you have it running a powershell command, then you should be able to get it to run a batch file...

Then in your batch file you can use CMail to send yourself a notification. Here is an example batch file, where i am sending from a Gmail account, using STARTTLS for encryption:

```
::E-mail Notification Script Using CMail

@ECHO OFF
ECHO Sending Mail with CMail.exe...

cmail.exe -host:exampleaccount@gmail.com:gmailapppassword@smtp.gmail.com:587 -starttls -to:recipient@example.com -from:senderaccount@gmail.com "-subject:Notification!" "-body:A File on the company drive has been modified!"

ECHO Email Sent.
```

NOTE: An alternative to FolderChangesView, in case it is helpful to anyone, may be RealTimeSync, as part of the FreeFileSync package. See [Here](https://freefilesync.org/manual.php?topic=realtimesync)